# How to require file via absolute and relative paths in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

There's a file, just a single file, there's no shards or anything else.

```
/alex/projects/inspector/inspector.cr
```

I want to require it in another file in another folder

```
/alex/projects/my-project/play.cr
```

This won't work

```
require "/alex/projects/inspector/inspector"
require "/alex/projects/inspector/inspector.cr"
```

This also not working

```
CRYSTAL_PATH=$CRYSTAL_ROOT/src:lib:/alex/projects/inspector

require "inspector"
require "inspector.cr"
require "./inspector"
require "./inspector.cr"
```

P.S.

I would like to **avoid using shards** etc. as I have no plans to share that file or publish it. It's just a file that used by couple of other files in different locations.

I solved it by creating symlink

```
ln -s /alex/projects/inspector/inspector.cr /alex/projects/my-project/inspector.cr

require "./inspector"
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `require` is only relative (as you learned from [your forum post](https://forum.crystal-lang.org/t/how-to-require-file-via-absolute-and-relative-paths-in-crystal/1582)). However, you were on the right track with `CRYSTAL_PATH`.

`CRYSTAL_PATH` is an [environment variable used by the Crystal compiler](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/using_the_compiler/index.html#environment-variables) which tells it where to look for dependencies. So instead of using it in code, as it appears you did, you should use it when building the executable:

```sh
CRYSTAL_PATH=$CRYSTAL_ROOT/src:lib:/alex/projects/inspector crystal build /alex/projects/my-project/play.cr
```

Note that `CRYSTAL_ROOT` must be defined for that exact command to work. If you need to find the current `CRYSTAL_PATH` in order to append to it, you can use `crystal env`.